# Grails/GGTS 2.4.2 not putting plugins on classpath?

Tags: grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to update an older 1.3 Grails project to the latest Grails/Groovy/etc.   So I downloaded Grails 2.4.2, Groovy 2.3, and Java 1.7.0_65.  Then I imported the project via Import->Grails.  I found out that plugins are now configured via the BuildConfig.groovy file, so I edited that with the plugins section and ran Grails Tools -> Update Dependencies.  None of my plugins appear on the classpath?  However, if I startup the plugin manager (which I'm not fully clear on why it is in the product as it states it won't do much after version 2.3...), it does list:

```
Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
mail                1.0.6            --  Provides Mail support to a 
running Grails application
routing             1.2.0            --  Routing capabilities using 
Apache Camel
routing-jms         1.2.0            --  JMS integration for the 
grails-routing plugin
shiro               1.2.1            --  Apache Shiro Integration for Grails
```

So *SOME* part of Grails seems to know about the plugins.  Also, if I delete the plugins from my $HOME/.grails/projects/myProject/plugins directory and re-run the Grails Tools -> refresh dependencies, I get both text on the console saying they are being installed and they come back to that directory.

The ONLY thing that seems abnormal, is that during the second set of files compiled (my project files) there ARE compile errors.  I expected these (for instances of grailsApplication / etc).  To fix them, I wanted to use GGTS - however, there are SO many compile errors in there from the plugins not being on the classpath it is not very feasible.

If anyone has ideas or suggestions for me to try that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a problem with GGTS not knowing what your grails work directory is.

You can check you *.project* file to see if the *.link_to_grails_plugins* resource is defined correctly.

GGTS may have created the .project like this

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>.link_to_grails_plugins</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>GRAILS_ROOT/projects/myProject/plugins</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

GRAILS_ROOT is a variable defined in your GGTS Preferences under General -> Workspace -> Linked Resources

You might have to add the variable if it's not there.
Set the value to the absolute path for $HOME/.grails and then try to refresh your dependencies.

Comment: Yes!  This was the problem - thank you.  While I always knew about that my old project, I never even looked for the .link_to_grails_plugins!  So I never would have figured it out.  One comment - even after I made the change the classpath was not updated - just need to restart GGTS to make it kick in.