# GGTS Eclipse is not recognising a plug-in I've added to my grails config

Tags: eclipse, grails, spring-tool-suite

I tried to add jodatime to my grails project within Eclipse GGTS. I added the line: compile ":joda-time:1.5" to my BuildConfig.groovy.

I did a clean and refreshed dependencies. The library was downloaded but Eclipse is not recognising any of the classes when I try to import them into a groovy class.

In my .project I see the link to the grails plugins

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>.link_to_grails_plugins</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>C:/Dev/GrailsTest/TekDays/target/work/plugins</location>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

I see the jodatime plugin in the directory

```
Directory of C:\Dev\GrailsTest\TekDays\target\work\plugins

2014/12/17  11:13 AM    <DIR>          .
2014/12/17  11:13 AM    <DIR>          ..
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          asset-pipeline-1.9.9
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          cache-1.1.8
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          database-migration-1.4.0
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          hibernate4-4.3.6.1
2014/12/17  11:12 AM    <DIR>          joda-time-1.5
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          jquery-1.11.1
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          scaffolding-2.1.2
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          tomcat-7.0.55
2014/12/11  02:44 PM    <DIR>          webxml-1.4.1
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)  31,378,694,144 bytes free
```

When I compile from the command line I'm fine, but in Eclipse it fails to recognise any of the jodatime package names.

I've already tried the advice at [Grails/GGTS 2.4.2 not putting plugins on classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908769/grails-ggts-2-4-2-not-putting-plugins-on-classpath) but that didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: Try issuing a "grails compile" first. I remember seeing something about a bug in the classpath setting that puts the contents of the target directory as the build path.

Comment: Possibly this one : https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1262

Comment: I'm on version 3.6.3-RELEASE of ggts and grails 2.4.4 so don't think it's STS-1262.

Comment: I also tried running the compile command but that didn't help either. It's a head scratcher